# Use groupBy on ng-repeat with angular-filter module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I use groupBy on ng-repeat with filter module ?

I have this :

```
<div ng-init="fields = session.getCountry()">

    <span ng-repeat="(country, value) in fields | groupBy: 'country.code'" >
        <span ng-bind="country.code"></span>
        <span ng-bind="country.name"></span>
        <span ng-if="$last === false">, </span>
    </span>

</div>
```

session.getCountry() return this :

```
[
{
    code: "1",
    country: {
        code: "au",
        name: "Australia",
    },
    name: "Free"
},
{
    code: "2",
    country: {
        code: "au",
        name: "Australia",
    },
    name: "Pay"
},
{
    code: "3",
    country: {
        code: "us",
        name: "United States",
    },
    name: "Free"
},
]
```

I would like to have this :

```
au Australia, us united States
```

but my result is :

```
au fi mx
```

I use angular-filter v0.5.7

> SOLVED

I use :

```
<div ng-init="fields = session.getCountry()">
    <span ng-repeat="field in fields | unique: 'country.code'" >
        <span ng-bind="field.country.code"></span>
        <span ng-bind="field.country.code"></span>
        <span ng-if="$last === false">, </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your ng-repeat like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in fields  | groupBy:'country.code' ">
```

Comment: I have the country.code, but I have not the country.name

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you should try to make your "country" items like this :

```
{
    code: "1",
    country: {
        code: "au",
        name: "Australia",
    },
    name: "Free"
},
```

Just change the "[" and "]" brackets.

Then you can just do this :

```
<span ng-repeat="field in fields | groupBy: 'field.country.code'" >
{{ field.country.code }}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Have you changed the data type returned by "session.getCountry() "? I suspect your country element is an item, and not an array like the JSON you pasted since it has array brackets